# Python Requests.Get - Giving Invalid Schema Error

Tags: python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Another one for you.

Trying to scrape a list of URLs from a CSV file. This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('TeamRankingsURLs.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('TeamRankingsOutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)


    for line in csv_urls:
        page = requests.get(line[0]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.findAll('div', {'class' :'LineScoreCard__lineScoreColumnElement--1byQk'})

        for r in range(len(results)):
            csv_output.writerow([results[r].text])
```

...Which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TeamRankingsScraper.py", line 11, in <module>
    page = requests.get(line[0]).text
  File "C:\Users\windowshopr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\windowshopr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\windowshopr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\windowshopr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 616, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\windowshopr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 707, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ï»¿https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/stat/runs-per-game?date=2018-04-15'
```

My CSV file is just a list in column A of several urls (ie. https://www...)

(The div class I'm trying to scrape doesn't exist on that page, but that's not where the problem is. At least I don't think. I just need to update that when I can get it to read from the CSV file.)

Any suggestions? Because this code works on another project, but for some reason I'm having issues with this new URL list. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the Traceback, `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ï»¿https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/stat/runs-per-game?date=2018-04-15'`

See the random character in the url, it should start from `https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/stat/runs-per-game?date=2018-04-15`

So first parse the csv and remove any random characters before the http/https using regex. That should solve your problem.

If you want to resolve your current problem with this particular url while reading csv, do :

```
import regex as re

strin = "ï»¿https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/stat/runs-per-game?date=2018-04-15"

re.sub(r'.*http', 'http', strin)
```

This will give you the correct url which request can handle.

Since you ask for the full fix of the path which is accessible in the loop, here's what you could do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import regex as re

with open('TeamRankingsURLs.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('TeamRankingsOutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)


    for line in csv_urls:
        page = re.sub(r'.*http', 'http', line[0])
        page = requests.get(page).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.findAll('div', {'class' :'LineScoreCard__lineScoreColumnElement--1byQk'})

        for r in range(len(results)):
            csv_output.writerow([results[r].text])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure why those special characters are being put in front of my URLs taken from the CSV because there's nothing in the CSV that suggests that? Anyway, is there a way to adapt this to work in the loop going through all of the URLs instead of just the one? When I try it with the requests.get part, I get a similar error? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible, Let me just edit the answer. Also could you please accept this answer, if it worked for you.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks so much for doing this for me. I was running in circles but now I understand. Will accept!